# rc.local not running on server boot

Tags: boot, server, scripts, startup

I have an issue with my rc.local, which isn't running automatically the command line contained inside, on server boot. However, running manually rc.local works fine and starts the script.

Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Here is my rc.local

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

sh '/home/[user]/azerothcore-wotlk/reboot.sh'

exit 0
```

And my reboot.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/screen -AmdS world /home/[user]/azerothcore-wotlk/acore.sh run-worldserver
/usr/bin/screen -AmdS auth /home/[user]/azerothcore-wotlk/acore.sh run-authserver
```

Status of the rc.local service:

```
$ systemctl status rc-local.service
● rc-local.service - /etc/rc.local Compatibility
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service; enabled-runtime; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service.d
             └─debian.conf
     Active: active (exited) since Wed 2021-05-19 22:01:41 IST; 2 days ago
       Docs: man:systemd-rc-local-generator(8)
    Process: 500 ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Warning: some journal files were not opened due to insufficient permissions.
```

rc.local and reboot.sh both have permissions:

```
$ ls -l /etc/rc.local
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 718 May 16 01:13 /etc/rc.local
$ ls -l reboot.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 [user] [user] 179 May 16 01:16 reboot.sh
```

By the way rc.local used to work awhile ago, but suddenly stopped for an unknown reason. I'm not an experienced Linux user, so I've read a lot of posts about this problem, and the most often recommendations was to: check if the rc.local has a shebang line (check!); Set proper permissions to rc.local and the script (check!); check the status of the service (check!).

After hitting a rock with rc.local, I decided to give a try to some other methods.

I tried with crontab:

```
crontab -e

@reboot sh /home/[user]/azerothcore-wotlk/reboot.sh
```

Not starting on server boot. Starting normally if run manually.

Also tried init.d

```
sudo su
nano /etc/init.d/reboot
```

contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
/home/[user]/azerothcore-wotlk/reboot.sh
```

Then:

```
chmod ugo+x /etc/init.d/reboot   
update-rc.d reboot defaults
```

Same result - not starting on boot.

Then tried to create a service:

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/acore.sh
```

contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

screen -AmdS world /home/[user]/azerothcore-wotlk/acore.sh run-worldserver
screen -AmdS auth /home/[user]/azerothcore-wotlk/acore.sh run-authserver
```

---

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/acore.sh
```

---

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/acore.service
```

contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=My daemon

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/acore.sh
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

```
$ systemctl start acore.service

==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to start 'acore.service'.
Authenticating as: ,,, ([user])
Password:
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
systemctl enable mydaemon.service
```

---

```
systemctl enable acore.service
```

Not working either.

At this point I have absolutely no idea what to do. As I mentioned above, I'm not an experienced Linux user, so any help will be appreciated!

Thank you!

Edit: As @terdon suggested, I added the lines

```
/usr/bin/touch /tmp/rc.has.run
```

to the beginning of the rc file)

and

```
/usr/bin/touch /tmp/reboot.has.run
```

to the beginning of the reboot script

Both files have been created in the `/tmp` folder after rebooting the server.

Edit2: **Thanks to @terdon** the problem is solved by adding 'sleep 60' in the beginning of the rc.local.

Comment: Where is your `screen` executable? You can check with `type screen`. Try replacing the `screen`  command in your script with the full path (e.g. `/usr/bin/screen`) and let us know if that makes any difference.

Comment: screen is hashed (/usr/bin/screen). I added the screen path in the script, but still not starting after reboot.

Comment: OK, please add that to your question (just edit the script and change it to use `/usr/bin/screen` so the next person to read it won't have the same question). Next thing to try is to add some debugging to check if the script is really not being launched. Add `/usr/bin/touch /tmp/rc.has.run` to the beginning of the rc file and `/usr/bin/touch /tmp/reboot.has.run` to the beginning of the reboot script, and then reboot and check `/tmp` and see if any files were created.

Comment: Done. Both files are created in /tmp

Comment: Ah! Now we're getting somewhere. So, we now know that both scripts are being executed. I suspect the problem might just be that they are running too soon before whatever else is needed for them to run has finished loading. So, change the `rc` file's command to this: `sh '/home/[user]/azerothcore-wotlk/reboot.sh' 2>/tmp/reboot.error.log`. That will redirect any error messages the script creates and you should be able to see what's happening.

Comment: reboot.error.log file have been created in /tmp, but it's empty.

Comment: Hmm. Have you checked if the `screen` process is actually running? After rebooting, do you see any output for `ps aux | grep '[s]creen`? Another thing to try would be adding a delay to the `reboot.sh` script: add `sleep 60` to the beginning to make it wait for a minute before launching `screen`, maybe that will help. I'll take another look tomorrow with a clear head.

Comment: Woah, sleep 60 did the trick! Now the script starts automatically. Thank you so much! You can actually post this as an answer if you want.

Comment: Yay! You're very welcome. Answer posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem isn't that the script isn't running, but that it is running too soon, before the system has finished setting everything up, and therefore fails because your machine isn't ready to run it yet. So a simple solution is to add a delay to the script so that it waits a bit before launching.

Edit your `reboot.sh` script, and add a `sleep` call:

```
#!/bin/sh

## wait for 60 seconds
sleep 60

/usr/bin/screen -AmdS world /home/[user]/azerothcore-wotlk/acore.sh run-worldserver
/usr/bin/screen -AmdS auth /home/[user]/azerothcore-wotlk/acore.sh run-authserver
```

You can experiment with the `sleep` value to find something that works and doesn't feel slow.

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time!